# Looping multiple variables to apply sound.Sound() psychopy function

Tags: python, loops, audio, psychopy

I am trying to apply `sound.Sound()` function to a numpy array in a loop. Specifically, I want to do below in a loop. a_wave to d_wave are the numpy arrays.

```
stim_a = sound.Sound(a_wave)
stim_b = sound.Sound(b_wave)
stim_c = sound.Sound(c_wave)
stim_d = sound.Sound(d_wave)
```

I've tried the loop below.

```
import sys
this = sys.modules[__name__]
import string

letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
a_d = letters[:4]
for x in range(len(a_d)):
    setattr(this, 'stim_%s' % a_d[x], sound.Sound('%s_wave' % a_d[x]))
```

But I get the following error as a result:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.83.01-py2.7.egg\psychopy\sound.py", line 389, in __init__
    self.setSound(value=value, secs=secs, octave=octave, hamming=hamming)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.83.01-py2.7.egg\psychopy\sound.py", line 146, in setSound
    raise ValueError, "setSound: could not find a sound file named " + value
ValueError: setSound: could not find a sound file named a_wave
```

I would very much appreciate it if I could get some advice on this matter. I insert the whole code below for reference.

```
from __future__ import division
from psychopy import sound
import sys
this = sys.modules[__name__]
import numpy as np
import string

#generate string lists
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
a_d = letters[:4]

sampling_rate = 44100 #in Hz
target_fq = 200
long_dur = 0.150
short_dur = 0.066
short_blank = 0.066
long_blank = 0.150
double_blank = 0.233

#short
short_index = np.array(range(int(round(short_dur / (1/float(sampling_rate)))-1)))
short_wave = np.sin(2*np.pi*target_fq*(short_index/float(sampling_rate)))
short_blank_wave = np.zeros(short_blank*sampling_rate) #Small fudge factor to bring total stim length to 4410

#long
long_index = np.array(range(int(round(long_dur / (1/float(sampling_rate)))-1)))
long_wave = np.sin(2*np.pi*target_fq*(long_index/float(sampling_rate)))
long_blank_wave = np.zeros(long_blank*sampling_rate)

#double blank
double_blank_wave = np.zeros(double_blank*sampling_rate)

#numpy arrays
a_wave = np.concatenate((long_wave, short_blank_wave, long_wave), axis=0)
b_wave = np.concatenate((short_wave, long_blank_wave, long_wave), axis=0)
c_wave = np.concatenate((long_wave, long_blank_wave, short_wave), axis=0)
d_wave = np.concatenate((short_wave, double_blank_wave, short_wave), axis=0)

for x in range(len(a_d)):
    setattr(this, 'stim_%s' % a_d[x], sound.Sound('%s_wave' % a_d[x]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are (in a remarkably convoluted way) simply constructing strings (e.g. `'a_wave'`) to pass to a sound object. The sound object naturally interprets those as a filename to open, which fails. i.e. note that the string `'a_wave'` does not correspond to the numpy array object `a_wave` that you are trying to refer to.

You could simply do something like this:

```
sound_stim = sound.Sound()

for sound_array in (a_wave, b_wave, c_wave, d_wave):

    for entry in sound_array:
        sound_stim.setSound(entry)
        sound_stim.play()
        # probably need some sort of delay loop here, as
        # playing doesn't block execution.
```

But as you haven't clearly expressed what you are trying to achieve, I'm just guessing here. Note that the arrays `a_wave` etc don't need to be numpy arrays at all, they could just be Python lists, which would simplify their construction. e.g.

```
a_wave = [long_wave, short_blank_wave, long_wave]
```

In general you're over-engineering your code. Keep it simple and Pythonic.

Comment: Thank you Michael! I ran the suggested loop but I got the error message (ValueError: Sound: bad requested frequency 0). Perhaps, assigning new variable names in a loop is really over-engineering my code in the first place.

Comment: This just sounds like an issue with using the sound API correctly to specify what you need. I don't have experience with feeding a sound a manually-crafted numpy array myself. Would suggest that you take that specific query to the forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org where I'm sure someone can help out.